# When to use quicksort, mergesort, and radix sort? (with regard to quantities rather than paradigms)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

I've seen plenty of questions asking whether quicksort or mergesort is 'better', and when to use each of them, but what I'd like to see is some input on when to use them with regard to the size of the data being sorted.
Let's say I have a number of *items*, whether they be ints or custom objects. I sort these items.

I see mergesort, in a way, as being the optimal case of quicksort (picking the median as the pivot) at every step, but with some overhead. So at a certain size, when the overhead is negligible in comparison to the consistent optimal nature of mergesort, it would make sense to use it in favor of quicksort.

Radix sort has a 'linear' runtime given that the number of digits of the keys being sorted on does not approach the number of separate items being sorted. However, radix sort also has a relatively large constant on its runtime to my knowledge as well.

If I recall from some testing in the past, it made sense to use mergesort when the number of *items* being sorted began to number in the millions, and radix in the high millions/billion range.

Am I reasonably accurate in these assessments? Can someone confirm, deny, or correct them to some extent?

(I'm talking about rather 'simple' implementations of each sort. Also, in the case of radix sort, let's say that the largest single key is no larger than twice the number of *items* being sorted. i.e. sorting 4,000,000 items, the largest possible key is 8,000,000)

**edit** - I would like some input on the generic number ranges that one of the given sorts is fastest. I provided some in the question, and that may have been a mistake. What I'd like to see in an answer is an opinion on the number ranges. I know quicksort tends to be the default since its usually 'good enough' and doesn't have the space complexity of merge and doesn't come with the worry of malicious data purposefully made with obscenely large keys (radix).

Comment: If *"the largest single key is no larger than twice the number of items being sorted"*, then a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) will work. The trade-off between quick sort and merge sort is *time versus space*. Quick sort may take more time, but merge sort requires O(n) additional space.

Comment: Thanks, but I do know counting sort will work, and that quicksort saves on space complexity,, please see my edit